# PHP Error : Maximum execution time of 1 second exceeded with Guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

I have an recurring error with PHP. When I run a script which uses Guzzle in CLI, it is working perfectly. When I run in from a website as the www user, the script crashed and in the apache logs, I find that it's from Guzzle.

here is the error : 
**AH01071**: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 1 second exceeded in _/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/MessageTrait.php on line 73\n'

I tried to rise the max_execution_time in the php.ini, and to use the ini_set() function, but I still get this error. Sometimes it's coming from other PHP files... I can't find out where it's coming from ? Thank in advance for any help

Answer (score -3):

have you tried with this?

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

before calling guzzle

Comment: then you should check `max_execution_time` variable after put this code. call `php_info()` and see. ALso, when PHP safe mode is enabled, set_time_limit won't work. Turn off safe mode and make yourself sure modified configuration is adjusted properly by calling php_info

Comment: I also modified php.ini and I set max_execution_time at 0 to be sure it is infinite

Comment: Weeird. Did you restart php-fpm after that? Have you checked variable list php_info() shows to find max_execution_time is set to 0 properly?

Comment: Check ini_get('max_execution_time');  right before you call guzzlehttp. I think some other library or something is overriding max_execution_time. What framework are you using?